# get label value in javascript through iframe

Tags: asp.net, javascript

i have an aspx page containing following code

```
<body>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function Hidee()
        {
        alert(window.frames["frame1"].document.getElementById("Label1").text);
        }
    </script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <iframe id="frame1"  name="frame1" class="frame" frameborder="0" src="Default4.aspx"></iframe>
         <a onclick="javascript:Hidee()" style="cursor: pointer">close</a>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

in Default4 page i have a label with id Label1 
when i click on close button i get **undefined** alert message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> getElementById("Label1").text

An HTMLLabelElement doesn't have a `text` property.

If it's a simple label that contains only a single Text node, you can say:

```
getElementById('Label1').firstChild.data
```

If it might contain more complicated text and element nodes, you'd have to iterate over them to pick up the text, or use the DOM Level 3 Core `textContent` property, with backup for IE which doesn't support it:

```
var label= frames['frame1'].document.getElementById('Label1');
var text= ('textContent' in label)? label.textContent : label.innerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
function Hidee() {
var ifr=document.getElementById("frame1"),
cd=ifr.contentDocument || ifr.contentWindow.document;
alert(cd.getElementById("Label1").innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: it says object required in alert line